# I am receiving multiple Web-responses in Single File , how to parse it in Unix

Tags: xml, linux, unix, xslt, xml-parsing

[WebResponse from SOAP POST Request][1]

I am getting below response in single file  :

Below responses are incomplete as i couldnt add such huge responses here so I kept only one element "TicketID"
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">S:Bodyns2:getStaticTicketDataResponse xmlns:ns2="http://soap.ws.tsp.com"><return>requestID>420</requestID>tspID>62</tspID><staticTicketDataList><StaticTicketData><ticketID>123</ticketID></S:Body></S:Envelope>`

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:getStaticTicketDataResponse xmlns:ns2="http://soap.ws.tsp.com"><return>requestID>420</requestID><tspID>62</tspID><staticTicketDataList><StaticTicketData><ticketID>124</ticketID></S:Body></S:Envelope>`

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:getStaticTicketDataResponse xmlns:ns2="http://soap.ws.tsp.com"><return>requestID>420</requestID><tspID>62</tspID><staticTicketDataList><StaticTicketData><ticketID>125</ticketID></S:Body></S:Envelope>`

I want to parse all the responses into a CSV file.

Final output should look like :
ticketId
123
124
125

this is SOAP request with dynamic TICKETID value in it :

````
"<soapenv:Header/>\n"+
"<soapenv:Body>\n"+
"<soap:getStaticTicketData>\n"+
"<arg0>\n"+
"<requestID>420</requestID>\n"+
"<tspID>62</tspID>\n"+
"<ticketIDs>\n"+
"<ticketID>"+ticket_id+"</ticketID>\n"+
"</ticketIDs>\n"+
"</arg0>\n"+
"</soap:getStaticTicketData>\n"+
"</soapenv:Body>\n"+
"</soapenv:Envelope>";```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbAFo.png
````

Comment: The code you show is not XML and cannot be processed with XSLT.

Comment: You appear to have cut off at least the first character of your lines. And you should include what you want the final CSV to look like too.

Comment: I added an image now , could you please check .It is a proper XML response only.@michael.hor257k    @shawn

Comment: **1.**  Please post your code in your question **as code**, not as picture. **2.** An XML document cannot have multiple XML declarations.

Comment: Images aren't any good. Fix your sample XML text instead.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am receiving such response while running the code through one application . They have dynamic parameters declared for posting the webrequest and receving multiple outputs as response capture in one File.

Comment: Added image will displays the response from Web in single file

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Sure , did that . Can any one help me with my request ?